How to connect htmx with webstocket
I am building a real-time chatroom using htmx connect with webstocket in Django, when I try to send a message,  the message is not showing and I am getting this error in the terminal "HTTP GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken=frNekEsvdZ6jdJp7gYMF7pvXpnO11m3J3vOpJ7XCsAKLogIBuUpuKizmufpWRKxN&body=hi+aneeb 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:54773]"
here my asgi.py file:
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'a_core.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from  a_realchat import routing 

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
    ),
})


here my routing.py file:
from django.urls import path
from .consumers import *

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/chatroom/chatroom_name",ChatroomConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

here my consumers.py:
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import GroupChat,GroupMessage
import json
class ChatroomConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope['user']
        self.chatroom_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['chatroom_name']
        self.chatroom = get_object_or_404(GroupChat,group_name=self.chatroom_name)
        self.accept()

    def receive(self ,text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        body = text_data_json['body']

        message = GroupMessage.objects.create(
            body=body,
            auther=self.user,
            group=self.chatroom,

        )

my .html file where i connecting the ws
    <form id="chat_message_form" class="w-full" 
                        hx-ext="ws"
                        ws-connect = "ws/chatroom/TalkAboutPython"
                        ws-send
                        _="on htmx:wsAfterSend reset() me"
                >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                </form>

